# Not able to click on filter on grid in selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

I am giving the code below where I need to click on the filter icon. please help me out

```
<thead class="k-grid-header" role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" scope="col" data-title="User Name" data-index="0" data-field="UserName" data-role="columnsorter">
            <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
                <span class="k-icon k-filter"/>
            </a>
           <a class="k-link" href="/Admin/AdminRoleGrid/Read?adminGrid-sort=UserName-asc">User Name</a>
        </th>
```

Comment: Which attribute is your filter icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it look that your locator is not fine. Here you need to identify your locator. I have write some xpath .. you can try them one by one... It can be as below:-

```
//a[@class='k-link' and contains(.,'User Name')]
```

OR

```
//a[@class='k-grid-filter']
```

OR

```
//span[class='k-icon k-filter']
```

OR

```
//th[@class='k-header k-filterable k-with-icon' and data-title='User Name']
```

You can also try to click using `JavascriptExecutor`

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your Xpath"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

==========================

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='k-grid-filter']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor) oBrowser;
executor1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element1);

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='adminGrid']/div[1]/table/thead/tr/th[1]/a‌​[1]/span"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) oBrowser;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I had tried all the above, out of them only second option is able to locate the element but was not able to click even though given .click();

Comment: All the other options were not even able to locate the element

Comment: have you tried 2nd locator with the JavascriptExecutor code I have provided in answer?

Comment: If your locator is locating the right element then JavascriptExecutor should work because it is directly operating on HTML DOM ... are you sure your locator is fine..  have you tried with firebug to locate xpath for you .. if not give a try

Comment: hi, 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='k-grid-filter']")).click();
when i had given click in the code, why it doesn't click and just locates the element, any reason? as i am weak in Javascript

Comment: Selenium will not through the exception if it finds the element.. But we have to sure that element is as same as we expected.. what if the "//a[@class='k-grid-filter'] is not your button .. in that case selenium have find the element but it will also perform click but nothing was happened because that element is not belongs to the button .... thats why I said you to identify the locator(xpath) with firebug .. have you tried that

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='k-grid-filter']")).click();
 WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='adminGrid']/div[1]/table/thead/tr/th[1]/a[1]/span"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: this is the code i had used, was able to locate the element which i need but not able to perform click operation

Comment: why are are not clicking the element using javascriptex.. you are still cliking it normally.. and what is .//*[@id='adminGrid']/div[1]/table/thead/tr/th[1]/a‌​[1]/span...

Comment: I have added the code in my answer and added click for both element .. have a try ... do you want to click on both\

Comment: kudos, finally got it. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `WebDriver` first. 
Follow below code, Your xpath will be `//*[@class='k-icon k-filter']`

```
    DesiredCapabilities dc=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("your-url");

    // code upto your filter icon

    // webelement of your filter icon
    WebElement webelement = driver.findElement(By.className("k-icon k-filter"));
    webelement.click();
```

you can find [here](http://www.guru99.com/first-webdriver-script.html) more about basics of `selenium-webdriver`.

Comment: What if I had to click on filter for different columns which have same class "k-icon k-filter" but different data-title such as User name, First Name, Last Name etc

Comment: @nic.jess then change your xpath there are various way to locate elements. You can also locate by id,linktext,css etc, Refer Element Locators In WebDriver section from http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2014/01/learn-selenium-webdriver-online-free.html. Defiantly you can get it.

Comment: Syntax error on token "class", AssignmentOperator expected after this token - when using By.class

Comment: Edited my answer, there was silly mistake, try again.

Comment: Also delete your answer actually it is part of question. I have edited your question already.

Comment: Firstly thanks for editing the Question. I had deleted it.
The code is not working. Basically in code I had given just
 WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
Do i need to give in the way which you have specified and why, when I am able to perform all the functions just giving in the above way

Comment: Second and third line of code, firefoxprofile. It is not mandatory. You can skip it. I have used implicit wait to driver. Basically it will wait for time which set until element locate. Other thing, code is not working so tell me which functionality is not working? If you have error log then it will become useful.

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector k-icon k-filter is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted

Comment: I guess Selenium is not able to identify to select which column it should filter because all filters have same class as i said earlier

Comment: Need to find the element with diff Locators as u said

Comment: One more thing.. Have you used implicit wait? Is your element visible and present during script? If not then you can put custom thread.sleep() for waiting purpose to load page or elements.